# Transformation Pose

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, transform, manipulator, pick-and-place

Hi I am doing a transform from the object to the base_link the orientation seems to be right but the positioning is wrong.Here is my code. i had to change the translation values as when i move foward it was moving backwards.

[image]

````
  static tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster br;
  geometry_msgs::TransformStamped transformStamped;

  const aricc_vision_msgs::Object& last_object = msg->objects.back();

    transformStamped.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
    transformStamped.header.frame_id = "camera_color_optical_frame"; // Camera Link used
    transformStamped.child_frame_id = last_object.name; // Object name
    transformStamped.transform.translation.x -= last_object.position.y; // Object position x
    transformStamped.transform.translation.y -= last_object.position.x; // Object position y
    transformStamped.transform.translation.z = last_object.position.z; // Object position z
    

    tf2::Quaternion q;
    
    q.setRPY(1.57, -1.57, -last_object.orientation.z);
    transformStamped.transform.rotation.x = q.x() ;
    transformStamped.transform.rotation.y = q.y() ;
    transformStamped.transform.rotation.z = q.z() ;
    transformStamped.transform.rotation.w = q.w() ;
    br.sendTransform(transformStamped);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  ros::init(argc, argv, "object_tf2_broadcaster");
  ros::NodeHandle node;
  ros::Subscriber sub = node.subscribe<aricc_vision_msgs::ObjectArray>("/re_dl_detection/YOLOv8RotateObjectDetection/dl_output", 1000, &poseCallback);
  ROS_INFO("Object_tf2_broadcaster node starting..");
  ros::Rate rate(10000); // 10 Hz
  ros::spin();
  return 0;
};```   
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/71pBE.png
````

Comment: Please edit your question clarify what you question is. Include what you want to see, what you are seeing what's different, and what you've done to debug it already.